# Set modification date to February the 30th

Tags: c++, file, date

It may sound bizzare but I have to set programmatically file modification date to 30th February. Is it possible to do so? Programming language doesn't matter.

Comment: You can try but what you will get is 1 or 2 March depending on the year.

Comment: You may want to ask your real question. Setting something to February 30th is probably not the real requirement. It is a workaround for something. Ask about *that*.

Comment: i tried seeking the date by changing the numeric value of timestam, but I get 2 March, I thought maybe there is some illegal value that yields 30 February

Comment: Then the answer is: no not really. You could imagine that you would not want illegal things in operating systems/file systems, thus many years of development have lead to removal such things as much as possible. Customers prefer a safe OS.

Comment: Which operating system is this?

Comment: Windows or Linux, I get such a task from my customer, maybe she's pulling my leg

Comment: I think she is. If you're wanting February 30th to be a distinct date then you can forget about Windows. (Perhaps you can imbue your own calendar into Windows - I'm no expert). On Linux you'll need to rewrite all the timings in a fork. Your epoch will no longer correspond to anyone else's epoch which will be lots of fun. If you have the budget then I'd hire someone from NASA or the ESA who has experience in ripping up operating systems in order to support leap seconds properly. Nobody does this correctly; not even Google.

Comment: If you want February 30 you can also forget about Unix, Linux, AIX, SunOS, HP-UX, every other Unix derivative too numerous to mention, OS/2, IBM IBJOB, Guardian, George III, RSTS/E, RT-11, RSX-11, Posix, and every other operating system I have used in the past 50 years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File modification is epoch timestamp (number of milliseconds since midnight 01.01.1970), it is the calendar in the locale that is giving that timestamp a meaning of year/month/day. All you need to do is create your own calendar with 30 days in February (it is probably not a easy task).

Comment: But in doing that, *all* times will be horribly off.

Comment: I left the common sense aspect outside the scope of the answer as the OP started the question with "It may sound bizzare".

Comment: @nvoigt maybe not if you only have 30 days in feb every 51 years ;) But it sounds like a bad idea anyhow.

Answer (score 4):

That depends on the file system. But normally, no. They do not save "text", they save a date. And a date is a point in time. For example a number of milliseconds since 1.1.1970. And that is interpreted as a date based on your locale.

There is no February 30th. You cannot set it to February 30th just as you cannot set it to Qurkunle 3rd. It does not exist.

Comment: "milliseconds since 1.1.1970" ignoring leap seconds, normally.